# save images uploaded from user gallery so other users can see it

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase database for saving my data. The user can upload his own personal photo as profile picture from gallery. I want other users to be able to see the photo as well. I am currently saving the image path in database but that only works fine if both users share the same device. So how to save image in database so it is accessible  by all users using different devices

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data) and show what exactly you have already tried.

Comment: I can't make sense of this question's goals. how would two other users see each other or is this just a list of every user?

Answer (score 0):

You must upload the image to Firebase Storage and store the download URL into the realtime database
**OR** ideally, convert the image to base64 string and save that to the user's UID. Just ensure you are compressing and resizing the image beforehand and validate its length *(length is relative to the image size)* through `Security Rules` or through `Cloud Functions`.

The resulting structure would be as follows:

```
users-
    UserID_A -
          name: "Steven"
          avatar: "(random Base64 string)"
    UserID_B -
          name: "Jane"
          avatar: "(random Base64 string)"
```

Reference: https://www.programmersought.com/article/67005590348/